# How to Display Only Logged in User's Data From Database Without Showing Other's Data?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, data-binding, asp.net-membership

When I load up a grid view (which is supposed to display data of that user). However, when I log in as a user and view the grid view it displays both the current user's data and others' data. I want it to only display the current logged in user's data.

How would I use `userid = convert.toint32(session["userId"].tostring())` to check my current logged in user's username and display only their data from the database's table?

Comment: You can set user's name as a session variable on page load, then bind it to the database query like: SELECT values FROM userTable WHERE UserID=SessionVariable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your query to get the data something like

```
"Select * from SomeTable Where UserId = @userId"
```

And then set the parameter to userid

Same way as you'd do a query based on user input.